# Got a strange error in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm writing a program in Fortran and I have this line in the program:

```
READ*,(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)
```

And I get this error in the compiler:

```
*** '*' must be preceded with an operand
*** '(' found where not expected
*** Compilation abandoned
```

When I put a number instead of the `*` the first error goes away

How can I fix these errors?

**EDIT:**

This Is My Full Code:

```
PROGRAM MATRIS
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER::M,N,I,J
REAL::AVG,VAR,LEAST,LARGEST,SUM,MIN_A,MAX_A
REAL,DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE::A,B
PRINT*,"PLEASE ENTER column,raw"
READ*,M,N
ALLOCATE(A(M,N),B(M,N))
OPEN(10,FILE="C:/TEMP.txt",STATUS="OLD",ACTION="READ")
OPEN(10,FILE="C:/output.txt",STATUS="REPLACE",ACTION="WRITE")
OPEN(10,FILE="C:/output_statistic",STATUS="REPLACE",ACTION="WRITE")
READ*,(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)
DO J=1,N
    DO I=1,M
       B(I,J)=A(I,J)+273.15
    END DO
END DO
WRITE(20,'(2(F6.2,2X))')((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)
REAL::R1,R2,R3,R4,R5
PRINT*,"PLEASE ENTER YOUR NUMBER"
READ*,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5
CALL REVERSE(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5)
PRINT*,R2,R3,R4,R5
CONTAINS
      SUBROUTINE REVERSE(A,D,E,F,G)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL,INTENT(IN)::A
      REAL,INTENT(OUT)::D,E,F,G
SUM=0.
VAR=0.
LARGEST=0.
LEAST=10000.
DO I=1,N
    READ*,A
    SUM=SUM+A                                       
    MAX_A=MAX(LARGEST,A)
    LARGEST=MAX_A
    MIN_A=MIN(LEAST,A)
    LEAST=MIN_A
    VAR=SQRT(VAR+(A-AVG)**2)
    AVG=SUM/N
    D=MAX_A
    E=MIN_A
    F=VAR
    G=AVG
END DO
RETURN
PRINT*,D/E/F/G
END SUBROUTINE REVERSE
END PROGRAM MATRIS
```

This should get a Matrix of the Temperature in `Celsius` And print the Minimum And Maximum, Average And Variance In `Kelvin`.

Comment: Could you please give the example of the "working" statement?  It's a little unclear to me exactly what you mean, as just replacing the first `*` with a number wouldn't be something I'd expect to work.  Also, when you edit, please add the tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: @francescalus I've Edited And Added The Full code

Comment: You are reading from unit `10` that you just open, I guess. If that is the case it should be `READ(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)` instead of `READ*,(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)`

Comment: Try replacing `READ*,(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)` with `READ(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks! That worked. Can You Take a look at Line 19 `REAL::R1,R2,R3,R4,R5` : `REAL cannot appear after executable statements` And Line 34 `READ*,A` : `A appears on the left hand side of an assignment yet has the INTENT(IN) attribute` too? I've got errors there.

Comment: No, I can't take a look at any questions asked in comments.  Too difficult to read.  If you have another question, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my (and @innoSPG's) comment as an answer, so this question can be ticked off.

This line

```
READ*,(10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)
```

contains a simple syntax error, the `*,` immediately after the `read` are not allowed there and the compiler gives up.  Simply remove them:

```
READ (10,*)((A(I,J),I=1,M),J=1,N)
```

Comment: Really with the `*` after `READ`?

Comment: I was wondering if I was missing something. I found out years after using this form that the print-like `READ *,args` is also allowed.